# Форматирование чисел на JS

Tags: javascript

Как на JS привести число вида:

9999999,99

В

9 999 999

Ищу решение, по аналогии с **number_format** в PHP

Answer (score 2):

Объект Intl.NumberFormat делает такие вещи. Документация [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Пример оттуда же

```
var number = 123456.789;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(number));
// → 123 456,789
```